# Output from fortran application not showing up in Matlab

Tags: macos, matlab, fortran, stdout, gfortran

I'm having some issues with output from a fortran application being executed from within Matlab.  We use Matlab to call a number of fortran applications and to display output and results.

I'm using gfortran on OSX to build one of these programs, which does a large amount of file output and a little output to stdout to track progress.  stdout output is accomplished mainly through print * statements, but I've tried write( * , * ) as well.  The program uses OpenMP, but none of the print * or write( * , * ) statements are performed within OpenMP parallel sections.Everything works fine when the program is executed from a terminal.  However, when the program is executed from within matlab, there is no output from stdout.  The file output works fine though.

Additionally, the same code, when compiled with Intel's ifort, displays its output in matlab without issue.  Unfortunately I don't have regular access to the Intel compiler.

I'm positive that the output is going to stdout (not stderr), and I've tried flushing both from within the code (call flush(6) & call flush(0)), but this doesn't seem to make a difference.

I'm not sure what could be causing this.  Any thoughts?

some relevant information:
OS: OSX 10.6.8 (64bit mode)

Matlab: R2012b

gfortran: 4.7.2 (obtained via fink)

compile flags: -cpp -fopenmp -ffree-line-length-0 -fno-range-check -m64 -static-libgfortran -fconvert=little-endian -fstrict-aliasing

**EDIT:**

I've done some more testing, creating a simple 'hello' program:

```
program printTest
write (*,*) 'hello'
end program
```

compiled with...

```
gfortran test.f90 -o test
```

which exhibits the same behavior.

I've also tried compiling with an earlier version of gfortran (4.2.1), which produced some interesting results.  it executes fine in terminal, but in matlab I get the following:

> > !./test
> >     dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: __gfortran_set_std
> >       Referenced from: /Users/sah/Desktop/./test
> >       Expected in: /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/sys/os/maci64/libgfortran.2.dylib
> >
> > dyld: Symbol not found: __gfortran_set_std
> >       Referenced from: /Users/sah/Desktop/./test
> >       Expected in: /Applications/MATLAB_R2012b.app/sys/os/maci64/libgfortran.2.dylib
> >
> > ./test: Trace/breakpoint trap

This leads me to believe its a library issue.  using -static-libgfortran produces the same result in this case.

Comment: How are you executing the program from matlab?

Comment: The method used normally within the actual matlab program is as follows:  
    system(['cd "',handles.indir,'";chmod u+x ./qp.exe',...
                        ';./qp.exe']);

the program is copied into a directory and then executed.

I've also tried navigating to the directory and running !qp.exe

Comment: Ok - as long as you have nothing to the left of the system call (no [xxx,yyy] = system(...  )

Answer (score 0):

I believe Matlab is a single threaded application.  When you invoke a multithreaded executive, I have seen various issues with piping the output back to Matlab.  Have you considered recompiling into a Fortran mex file?

Comment: Matlab does have some parallel capabilities.  See parfor loop structure for an example.  Additionally, it strikes me as odd that the same exact code on the same exact computer in the same exact conditions works if it is compiled with Intel's compiler.  

As for compiling to a mex file, no I have not yet tried that.  Thus far I have tried to avoid doing so because of the changes in the rest of the system this would require.

Comment: True, Matlab add-ons allow for multi-threaded performance, but I am fairly certain it is a single threaded application.

Comment: That very well could be.  However, my edit above shows that the problem is not a result of openMP/parallel processing.  A simple program which just prints 'hello' doesn't even work in my setup.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure a mex file would print to stdout any better than a standalone executable.

There are other options. One is to write(append) all your diagnostics to a file and just look at the file when you want to. Emacs, for example, automatically "revert"s the contents of a file every second or whatever you set the interval to. Another option might be to convert the fortran source into matlab source (see f2matlab) and keep it all in matlab.

bb

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  The file output might be a viable option, though I'm not very excited about it.  Converting to matlab code is probably not going to work.  The executable is built from ~20,000 LOC and is my main goal is to make it fast (hence the OpenMP).  I think converting to matlab code would be a step in the wrong direction with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [system function documentation](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/system.html)

> > [status, result] = system('command') returns completion status to the status variable and returns the result of the command to the result variable.
> >
> > [status,result] = system('command','-echo') also forces the output to the Command Window.

So you should use '-echo' parameter to the system call to see the output directly in the command window

```
system(['cd "',handles.indir,'";chmod u+x ./qp.exe',... ';./qp.exe'], '-echo')
```

or you can assign the stdout to a variable:

```
[ret txt] = system(['cd "',handles.indir,'";chmod u+x ./qp.exe',... ';./qp.exe'])
```

Comment: No such luck, unfortunately.  I had high hopes for the -echo option, but neither method worked.

Comment: @ScotHalverson Does the test program also not work? What is returned by the 'system' call in ret and txt when you run the simple test program?

Comment: nope, didn't work for the test app either.  
ret is 0, text is an empty string ('')


    [ret test] = system('./test')


    ret =


    0



    test =


    ''



    >> system('./test', '-echo')


    ans =

    0

Comment: @ScotHalverson well, that is not too good :) I guess it has something to do with the fact that you are using Mac. Maybe change your gfortran compiler?

Comment: I've tried several versions of gfortran, going back to 4.2.3, all of which seem to exhibit this problem.  At the moment, I'm limited to gfortran.  g95 doesn't support OpenMP, and I'm not aware of any other F/OSS fortran compilers that do.

Comment: @ScotHalverson I more mean the provider of your gfortran. [Here](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries) is a list of binary distributions. Also, does Xcode not have it? They have recently released commandline tools, which are significantly smaller than all of xcode.

Comment: I believe Xcode does not contain gfortran.  I've tried a couple additional versions of the compiler from your link, but again I'm experiencing the same thing.